# how to suspend job in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Hi i am creating an application that executes the method of a class based on a cron expression. For that i am using spring quartz in which i have to configure all these stuffs in my spring-file it works fine and jobs are executing based on the cron expression, But now i want to suspend the next execution of particular job in java class based on the choice of a user from UI. Then is there any way to do this ??

can i get the details of all running job it the context ? if so then i can filter the jobs and   try to suspend that job for next execution.

Comment: Whats the business condition, on which you wish to skip? is there any? If yes then model that condition as job logic ( if(condition) then run else skip...)

Comment: thanks blob for reply. I am scheduling through cron expression that is every Monday or every minute based on cronExpression now if i want to skip execution for only next time then how can we do it?

Comment: Just remove the job from the scheduler and readd it when the user reenables it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it work by use of following code

stdScheduler is a scheduleFactoryBean

```
 String groupnames[] = stdScheduler.getJobGroupNames();
 for (String groupName : groupnames) {
     String[] jobNames = stdScheduler.getJobNames(groupName);
     for (String jobName : jobNames) {
            if (jobName.equals("jobName")) {
                    stdScheduler.pauseJob(jobName, groupName);
            }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Inject your [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html). Use it's `getScheduler` method to obtain a quartz [Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html) and use [rescheduleJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#rescheduleJob%28org.quartz.TriggerKey,%20org.quartz.Trigger%29) or other methods from quartz API to perform your task.

Answer (score 5):

We can use the stdScheduler.pauseJob(JobKey jobKey) method to reduce the number of loops mentioned in the code above

Comment: we have just jobName is available so i think we have to iterate through loop. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you got hold of the SchedulerFactoryBean by injection or somehow else there are the convenience methods:

```
schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().standby();
schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().start();
```

When using Quartz directly also this works:

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;

...
scheduler.standby();
...
scheduler.start();
```